# phonegap - device is not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova

When I launch the app, it will open `index.html` which run this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady, false);
    });
</script>
```

in `app.js`

```
var app = {
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        alert(device.model);
        window.location.replace('pages/home.html');
    },
};
```

it will alert `device.model` and redirect to `pages/home.html`.

in `pages/home.html`,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert(device.model);
    });
</script>
```

on the first alert i get the device model correctly, but after redirecting to `pages/home.html`, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: device is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Device is being provided by phonegap/cordova plugins, that are not being loaded on your pages/home.html. Moreover, device should be available on deviceready not documentready event.